# While loop running infinitely, don't understand why

Tags: java, android

The `while` loop is running infinitely. Could some please tell me why? I've tried a different method, but it didn't work for me.

Answer and help solve problem
whats wrong written me don't print exit status

```
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, host);
            session.setPassword(passWord);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();
            System.out.print("Conected");
            channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            ops = channel.getOutputStream();
            ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);
            channel.connect();
            //Log.e(Keyid,"Channel Connected");
            ps.println("ls");
            //  ps.println("dir");
            //give commands to be executed inside println.and can have any no of commands sent.
            ps.close();
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
           // BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            //System.out.println(input.ready());
            //String str = input.readLine();


            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line= buffer.readLine();
            while (line != null && !line.equals("")){
              //  length = length + line.length();
                line= buffer.readLine();
                System.out.println(buffer.readLine());

            }
            System.out.println("Exit");

           /* while(buffer.readLine() != null){
                System.out.println(buffer.readLine());
                System.err.println(buffer.ready());

            }*/
```

Comment: Btw..you'll be printing alternate lines with above logic

Comment: Which other method did you try? Have you read the javadocs for the `readLine` and `equals` methods?

Answer (score 0):

Use this
    while(dataIn.readLine != null)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having here is that the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method compares strings. But the [`readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method is returning a logical `null` and not a "Null" string. Hence, the comparison fails.

Try replacing it with this:

```
while (dataIn.readLine() != null){
```

Comment: not working  while (dataIn.readLine() != null)       but me ask         DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream()); for use while loop